# Move users in Discord to a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I use Node.js and Visual Studio Code to program my own Discord bot.
My Problem:
When I enter the command `#tellasecret @example`, it should move the sender of the message and the person mentioned to a separately created voice chat. After the two people have left the chat, the voice chat should be removed again.

It should go like this:
1: Create chat in a specific category
2: Move both users into this chat
3: Wait until both users leave the chat
4: Delete the chat

Can someone help me with such a problem?

(I'm sorry for my bad english grammar.)

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if the users were already in a voice channel.

You can use [`guild.channels.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) to create the channel.

Then you can use [`message.author.voice.setChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel) to move the user to the channel.

Then you can use [`channel.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) to check if the channel is empty. You can do this by writing a function that checks `if (channel.members === 0)` every x minutes using [`client.setInverval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval) then obviously if it's true, use [`channel.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=delete) to delete the channel.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! :)